# How do I search for and retrieve a single piece of data from an sqlite database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I am currently making this program as part of my computing coursework. In my program I have created a database `'Records.db'` which holds the user information. The table is called *Users* and the layout is; `Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Username STRING, Password STRING, First_Name STRING, Surname STRING`.

I am trying to code a login for users. Currently my code is as follows:

```
Login for users
import sys
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('Records.db')

Login = False

    while Login is False:
        u_name = input("Enter your username: ")
        p_word = input("Enter your password: ")
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT Password AND First_Name AND Surname FROM Users WHERE Username='"+u_name+"'")
        if Password == p_word:
            print("Welcome",First_Name,Surname+"!")
            Login = True
        else:
            print("The Username/Password is incorrect. Please check your input and try again!")
```

I keep getting an error saying that the variable Password is not defined. But I don't know how to retrieve it using SQLite. I thought that `cur.execute("SELECT Password AND First_Name AND Surname FROM Users WHERE Username='"+u_name+"'")` will return Password to be printed/used etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three things wrong here. I'm not going to give you the answer since this is homework, but hopefully this will help.

Firstly, your SQL syntax is incorrect. You don't use AND like that: you seperate the columns with commas.

Secondly, `execute` doesn't actually fetch the result. You need to do `cur.fetchone()` for that.

Thirdly, you have failed to understand how variables work. Even once you have the result, it is not automatically assigned to a local variable called Password. You need to take the data returned by the cursor and assign it to that variable.